# Initializing layers in Caffe Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am working on Constitutional Neural Network using [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/).
I have a prototxt file with layer "hungarian". That layer has two additional top layers `box_confidences` and `box_assignments`.

```
layer {
  name: "hungarian"
  type: "HungarianLoss"
  bottom: "bbox_concat"
  bottom: "boxes"
  bottom: "box_flags"
  top: "hungarian"
  top: "box_confidences"
  top: "box_assignments"
  loss_weight: 0.03
  hungarian_loss_param {
     match_ratio: 0.5
     permute_matches: true
  }
}
```

Then that `box_confidences` is used in another layer `box_loss` as bottom

```
layer{
  name: "box_loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "score_concat"
  bottom: "box_confidences"
  top: "box_loss"
}
```

My queries are

(1)Do I need to setup layers for these `box_confidences` and `box_assignments`?

(2)If necessary, how to setup layer in this prototxt file? That layer is just holding blob data and how these two layers are used in the `HungarianLossLayer` class member function can be seen as

```
void HungarianLossLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom, const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top){
    ...............
    ...............
    ...............
    Dtype* top_confidences = top[1]->mutable_cpu_data();
    ...............
    ...............
    ...............
    for (int i = 0; i < num_pred; ++i) {
        top_confidences[n * num_pred + i] =
          assignment[i] < num_gt_[n] ? Dtype(1) : Dtype(0);
        Dtype* top_assignments = top[2]->mutable_cpu_data();
        top_assignments[n * num_pred + i] =
          assignment[i] < num_gt_[n] ? assignment[i] : Dtype(-1);
    }
    ...............
    ...............

}
```

I just put `.....` for some other codes not to be messy.

So `box_confidences` and `box_assignments` are just data blobs and size is `num_pred`. WIthout running the code, it is hard for me to know the value of `num_pred`.

What could be the best way to setup these two layers in prototxt file?

Answer (score 0):

`box_confidences` and `box_assignments` are the feature maps (or intermediate activations) output by the `HungarianLoss` layer.  No manual setup for this memory is necessary and you can safely provide them as bottom blobs for subsequent layers (like your `SoftmaxWithLoss`) in the network